# looping in json - jquery

Tags: jquery, json

```
{
"info": {
    "limit": "0",
    "xdata": {
        "hospital": {
            "name": "qwewe",
            "street": "cxcxc"
        },
        "factory": {
            "name": "wrwr",
            "street": "xzcc"
        },
        "industry": {
            "name": "lll",
            "street": "sdfdsfdf"
        }
    }
    }
```

How can I print the contents of `xdata`? I.e I want data of hospital, factory & industry 
I'm using `$.each` jQuery loop but can't get the details to hospital.

Comment: this is a valid json (chkd in jsonlint) .. just copied a part of it..

Comment: your_data.info.xdata.hospital.name;

Comment: You're missing a } at the end. Unfortunately I can't edit the question myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try next

```
xdata = your_data.info.xdata;

for (xd in xdata) {
  console.log('Name: ' + xdata[xd].name);
  console.log('Street: ' + xdata[xd].street);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
var data = {
"info": {
    "limit": "0",
    "xdata": {
        "hospital": {
            "name": "qwewe",
            "street": "cxcxc"
        },
        "factory": {
            "name": "wrwr",
            "street": "xzcc"
        },
        "industry": {
            "name": "lll",
            "street": "sdfdsfdf"
        }
    }
}};

$.each(data.info.xdata, function(key, value) {
    var type = key; // e.g. hospital/factory/industry
    var name = value.name;
    var street = value.street;

    // do something with the values
    console.log(type, name, street);
});
```

Like this? To be honest the JSON isn't really formatted awesomely. The XDATA would be better off containing an array of objects but meh.

For more see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fZBYG/1/ be sure to have your console open.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you -- http://jsfiddle.net/ZE47n/7/

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(info.xdata, function(key, value) {
    // key is equal to hospital, factory, industry
    // valus is equal to { "name": "qwewe", "street": "cxcxc" }, ...
    // this in the scope is the same as arguments[1] - value;
    // this === value
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var json = $.parseJSON(j);
//console.log(json.info.xdata);
$.each(json.info.xdata,function(k,v){
console.log(v.name+" -- "+ v.street);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KmSBh/5/)